# Google Maps transparent image overlay

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Im looking for some examples of a transparent fixed postion image that overlays a map. When moving the map, the transparent image should not move and the markers should appear on top of the image.

Does anyone know of any examples?

Answer (score 2):

There's a way with a div on top of another one. It positions a + marker over the center of the map.

http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-samples-v3/source/browse/trunk/geocoder/getlatlng.html

the crosshair image is http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-samples-v3/source/browse/trunk/geocoder/crosshair.gif

Test here: http://jsfiddle.net/Q27DD/1/

Comment: Perfect. Now to figure out how to get the markers to appear on top of the overlay.

Comment: Hi Heitor. I just modified your fiddle a bit, so it does not rely on an external image. Also, by using `pointer-events:none` in CSS, any mouse or touch events should pass right through. Haven't tested in legacy browsers though. http://jsfiddle.net/4vrzgrx1/2/