# Overlay text on a google map without removing dom events

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to have a time overlayed on a google map but I want it statically positioned in the bottom right corner regardless of panning and zooming. I know I can do this by listing to the bounds change event and repositioning it but that seems quite dirty. The reason I want it as an overlay is because I want it to not take over the mouse events for panning or zooming.

Comment: Have you seen this similar question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9795644/google-maps-transparent-image-overlay

Comment: I have seen similar examples but the problem is if you click the crosshair you cannot drag the map

Answer (score 0):

I would look at the [InfoBox library](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/docs/reference.html), [this example](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/examples/infobox-label.html) looks like what you want, just keep its position fixed to the map div rather than to the map.

Answer (score 0):

You mean like the one we usually see at the bottom in the google map-
[image]

You can use CSS for this and its easy.
The css that maps.google uses is-

```
  bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 95px;
    z-index: 1000001;
}
```

So set your content in the div with this class. This div will be a sub div of your map holding div

Comment: Thanks, That is what I want but it prevents the panning and zooming of the map. I was hoping there was a map pane that would allow me to do this but not block the map mouse events